# Optimal version of Linux for T61 laptops

Tags: laptop

I have some Lenovo T61 laptops, which I want to convert to Linux (from WinXP or Win7). Being a novice I wonder

a) which Ubuntu-version is most suitable
b) other software i.e. BIOS etc. you would recommend to change.

The computers are intended for running surveillance cameras, simple office-work and standard internet nonsens (Facebook, web-mail, internet chit-chat)

Thank you very much in advance for your assistance.

Best regards
Ivar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu with unity desktop might be a little heavy on that computer making it sluggish. That laptop comes standard with anywhere between 512mb - 2gb of RAM. If you are on the lower end I would recommend Lubuntu, or possibly Xubuntu. If that is the t61-P version it will have double the standard video 128mb RAM making it 256 with a slightly faster gpu core. If you have the P version and want regular Ubuntu desktop I think its a safe try. If it is not the P version you might want to start off with Lubu or Xubu. The latest 15.xx versions should work just fine any way your go.

There should be no need to change the bios or bios settings on that specific laptop to run Linux.

Comment: Thank you very much for a very detailed and understandable answer.
Best regards
Ivar

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Xubuntu 15.10 on my T61 with 3GB of memory. It works just fine. But I installed the Middleton-BIOS and inserted a SATAII-harddrive which made it a little more responsive. 
After much hassle I managed to install thinkfan so that the fan is quieter.
So, I think most distros with a lightweight DE will work.